# XCode IDE does not support older documents after updating to Lion

Tags: iphone, xcode, xib, osx-lion

Today I tried to work on an older application and got this message:

"This version of Interface Builder does not support documents of type "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Document (XIB 3.x)" targeting "iPhone/iPod touch"."

I never had that before and just can imagine it happened after I updated yesterday my System to OS X Lion.

What could I do now? It looks I can't edit any of my older applications? How would I update the xib Files so they work with Lion?

Comment: Just checking, have you updated to Xcode 4.1? Apart from that I don't know.

Comment: yes, found out... with Xcode 4.1 it works again.. puhhh :@

Comment: how could i close this post now?

Comment: I'll answer, and you can choose it as correct. I only commented because I thought that suggestion itself wasn't worth an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try updating Xcode to 4.1. I suspect Apple wouldn't just kill support for 3.* projects.

Comment: Thanks, this suggestion helped me get things going too.